# Cordova/Ionic Firebase Auth Persistent Login

Tags: angularjs, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

This issue is for an app built with Ionic/Cordova/Firebase.

Android and IOS devices randomly wipes out localstorage. Whenever this happens, users of the app are asked to login once more. Authentication is done with: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Firebase now uses `indexedDB` to store the Auth state. This is more reliable than `localStorage`. Please upgrade to the latest version and you should no longer encounter this issue. Note that there is currently some issue with the implementation. Not sure if it affects Cordova but the fix should be out this week: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/627

Comment: The problem still persists with version 4.12.1. Will now try the 4.13.0 and will update you of the outcome.

Comment: Make sure `indexedDB` is enabled in your cordova app. Otherwise, Firebase Auth will fallback to `localStorage`.

Comment: According to the Cordova documentation, indexedDB is not supported on IOS. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#indexeddb

Or maybe I am missing something?

BTW thanks a lot for your prompt respose.

Comment: Hmm, try to use a Cordova indexedDB plugin. Here is one provided by Microsoft: https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-indexedDB

Comment: Still no luck with the indexedDB plugin.